# Convert REST query to Linq query

Tags: wcf, linq, entity-framework, rest, wcf-data-services

Is there any way to convert http request query(also known as Web Data Services URLs) as:

```
Customers(1)/Orders?$ ?$filter=not endswith(ShipPostalCode,'100')
```

to linq query and execute it against database?

I'm writing a WCF service with entity framework and I need to provide something like data service, but not really..., only in one, two mothods, so I need to parse the http request and execute the linq query against database to get data and then return it.

Answer (score 1):

If it is limited, you could always write your own implementation, see [this article](http://blog.bvsoftware.com/post/2008/02/27/How-to-create-a-Dynamic-LINQ-Query-Programmatically.aspx)

Comment: This doesn't address the question at all

Answer (score 0):

If this is a WCF Data Services (OData) service try [Add Service Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd673931.aspx).  This will allow for a client proxy using [IQueryable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.iqueryable.aspx) interfaces.

Comment: This is not Data Service. And I have not mean how to consume wcf services. I just want to execute url request against the database.

Comment: you could try RESTful WCF or an ASP.Net MVC action/custom route.  How generic do you need this?

Comment: you may want to just use data services.  Less code for you to maintain later.  Compared to the mess you will need for the filter parsing.